# What's the simplest way to revert/undo an autocmd Filetype call (Vim)?

Tags: vim

I using the following setup for Markdown files:

```
autocmd Filetype mkd call SetMarkdownOptions()
function SetMarkdownOptions()
  highlight NonText ctermfg=white   " Match the tildes to your background
  set background=light
  call lexical#init()
  "call textobj#sentence#init()
  set foldcolumn=12                 " Add a left margin
  set guifont=Fantasque\ Sans\ Mono\ 12
  set formatoptions+=t
  highlight! link FoldColumn Normal " Make it the background colour
  set laststatus=0                  " No statusbar
  set linespace=3 
  set nonumber                      " No line numbering
  colorscheme pencil
  set showtabline=0                 " don't show the tab bar
  set textwidth=63
  map <leader>s dwwP
  noremap Q gqap
  nnoremap <leader>t :OnlineThesaurusCurrentWord<CR>
endfunction
```

But the settings remain there if I open another file type. Is there an easy way to undo/revert that `autocmd Filetype` call?

Answer (score 2):

Filetype-specific options and mappings must be as *local* as possible to prevent them from "leaking":

```
setlocal foldcolumn=12
nnoremap <buffer> <leader>s dwwP
```

Refer to `:help 'option'` to see if that option is global or local.

I'd suggest placing those settings in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`.

Comment: This will not work for window-local options such as `'number'`, these options will persist even when changing buffers.

Answer (score 2):

The `b:undo_ftplugin` variable is set in all the standard distributed filetype plugins, and Vim will execute that variable when it switches filetypes, to undo all the stuff in the plugin.

So, in addition to using the "local" version of global-local options if available, you can just tie into that variable to restore the settings you're modifying.

For example, the standard markdown ftplugin has:

```
if exists('b:undo_ftplugin')
  let b:undo_ftplugin .= "|setl cms< com< fo< flp<"
else
  let b:undo_ftplugin = "setl cms< com< fo< flp<"
endif
```

You could do something similar. Note how commands are *appended* to the variable if the variable already exists, using `|` to chain it together with whatever is already in the variable.